# Margin changes in every page in HTML Django Template

Tags: html, css, django, layout, django-templates

I have created a django template from the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .grid-container {
            width: 21cm;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .page {
            width: 21cm;
            height: 29.7cm;
            padding-top: 1.5362cm;
            padding-bottom: 1.5362cm;
            padding-left: 0.5122cm;
            padding-right: 0.5122cm;
        }

        .grid-row {
            display: flex;
        }

        .grid-col {
            margin-left: 0.0854cm;
            margin-right: 0.0854cm;
            width: 9.9024cm;
            height: 3.7552cm;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
    {% for page in imglist %}
    <div class="page">
        {% for row in page %}
        <div class="grid-row">
            <div class="grid-col">
                    <span style="text-align: center">
                        Yantraksh Logistics Pvt Ltd
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ row.image }}" alt="" srcset="">
                        <br>
                        {{ row.label }} <br>
                        {% if row.lname  %}
                        {{ row.lname }}
                        {% else %}
                            _____
                        {% endif %}

                    </span>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-col">
                    <span style="text-align: center">
                        Yantraksh Logistics Pvt Ltd
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ row.image }}" alt="" srcset="">
                        <br>
                        {{ row.label }}<br>
                        {% if row.lname  %}
                        {{ row.lname }}
                        {% else %}
                            _____
                        {% endif %}
                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Th first page is rendered correctly but as soon as the pages increase the margin starts reducing and the page starts merging together, I am not familiar with this, so any help is appreciated.

I am adding the first page and 9th page for better understanding

First Page:

[image]

Ninth Page:

[image]

Please Help!!!

Margin is set to None in Printer, Scale Default and Size A4

Comment: You could look into `page-break-before` or `page-break-after` CSS rules if you want to force elements to be on separate pages

Comment: @IainShelvington Actually I am not familiar with css, can you help more specifically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not removing default padding and margin that is added to `body` and `html`. Also to remain in the safe side decrease the page height from `29.7cm` (although this is the correct height), and introduce `page-break` as suggested in the comment. Also, remove the flex given to `.grid-container` for exact measurement.

```html
    <style>
        @media print {

        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body, html {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .grid-container {
            width: 21cm;
            /* display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between; */
        }

        .page {
            width: 21cm;
            height: 29.5cm;
            padding-top: 1.5362cm;
            padding-bottom: 1.5362cm;
            padding-left: 0.5122cm;
            padding-right: 0.5122cm;
            break-after: always;
            page-break-after: always;
        }

        .grid-row {
            display: flex;
            height: 3.7552cm;
        }

        .grid-col {
            margin-left: 0.0854cm;
            margin-right: 0.0854cm;
            width: 9.9024cm;
            height: 3.7552cm;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
```